# Does a replicaset with 3 replicas need an arbiter?

Tags: mongodb

We are running a MongoDB database in HA mode on our k8s cluster. Our helm chart defines three replicas (with persitence: enabled: false) and one arbiter.

Since 3 replicas + 1 arbiter is an evil even number, I would love to know if the arbiter only comes into play when one replica goes down to ensure an odd number of electors to determine the new primary node, or is using an arbiter wrong when having defined an odd number of replicas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: ( Better option since having more ARBITER's is easy in k8s)

You may need to add 1x more ARBITER , 5x total voting members will allow you to keep the PRIMARY even 2x of the DATA members die simultaneously at the same time.

Option 2:

You remove the ARBITER since with 4x members and two down the PRIMARY will switch to SECONDARY since there will be no majority , but if you keep it election expected to be faster with 3x votes when only one member die.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Not sure about 2 arbiters tbh. I think I would either need 4 replicas + an arbiter, or just three replicas without arbiter. Following article says "Knowing this, it should be obvious that you either want 0 arbiters or 1...but never, ever more." -> https://www.openmymind.net/Does-My-Replica-Set-Need-An-Arbiter/

Comment: afcourse having data members is better then arbiters but expensive , but in general you better have odd number of total 3,5,7  nodes ,  max  possible is 7x voting members.

Comment: Thanks. Although it seems that using multiple arbiters is kind of an anti-pattern. See here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/#concerns-with-multiple-arbiters

Comment: I would say in general avoid arbiters and stick with the 3x data nodes and one more non-voting HIDDEN  member where you will take backups  and  also will reconfigure as voting SECONDARY in case you need to perform some maintenance in some of the other members ...

Comment: I think the confusing part was, that when using 3 replicas one fails the cluster would end up with 2 replicas (which is an even number). But the documentation says somewhere that it's not about the number of available nodes but the number of total nodes. That being said we have persistence disabled and therefore backups are not needed. We use MongoDB more as a cache which can do geo-spatial queries.

Comment: About Option 1 where you suggest 3 replicas and 2 arbiters. This isn't possible with the Bitnami helm chart. Either you define the arbiter or you don't. I haven't seen the possibility to define the number of arbiters. It can only be enabled or disabled. -> https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/16bf61483532b0858d3e16586450fa6cce12f5b8/bitnami/mongodb/values.yaml#L1015

Comment: In that case stick with only 3x replicaSet members they are completely enough , if you loose the full replcaSet you will reload the data from scratch ...   , when you loose one member you will have 2x alive(majority)  > 1x dead that will keep the  PRIMARY on.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a bunch for your patience.

Comment: Note that if you have 3 replicas and 2 arbiters, the majority will be 3, so you will not be able to complete a majority write if any one of the replicas goes down.